# "JRE 1.3 or higher must be installed!" / "JDK 1.3 or higher must be installed!" errors installing JAI 1.1.3 on Windows 7 (x64)

Tags: windows-7, java, windows-7-x64, jai

I am getting these errors...

[image: "Severe: JRE 1.3 or higher must be installed!"]
[image: "Severe: JDK 1.3 or higher must be installed!"]

**Severe: JRE 1.3 or higher must be installed!**

**Severe: JDK 1.3 or higher must be installed!**

...when installing JAI (Java Advanced Imaging) 1.1.3 on Windows 7 (x64), with JRE 7 (1.7) installed at "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7" and JDK 7 (1.7) installed at "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0".

Following http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/INSTALL.html#Windows, specifically this is what I did:

Visited:

- http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/
- http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/ (latest version)

Downloaded:

- http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jdk.exe
- http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jre.exe
- http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586.exe
- http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586.jar.zip

EDIT (QUESTION): It would be great if someone could break down the difference between these files. The instructions at http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/INSTALL.html#Windows do not go into enough detail and assume you already know what's what.

EDIT: As noted in the comments below, the .exe are exclusive installs, but I wished to install them to all three locations (to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Sun Microsystems\Java Advanced Imaging 1.1.3" as well as to my JDK and JRE locations), as I was not sure which I would need at my work as a Java developer. As far as I know, I just need to install the JDK version, and the .zip is a manual install of the same thing. I am not sure though! Unverified.

Installed:

- jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586.exe (installed fine)
- jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jre.exe <---- this is what causes one of the errors.
- jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jdk.exe <---- this is what causes one of the errors.

The errors appear to be the same issue of not finding where Java (JRE and JDK) is installed.

I have the following environment variables set:

- JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0
- Path = ...;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin

EDIT: This makes me think the problem is something deeper than environment variables, as there's no environment variables for JRE like there is for JDK (i.e., JAVA_HOME), right?

Fixes I have tried (to no avail):

- Re-installing*.
- Re-downloading and re-installing*.
- Adding "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin" to "Path" and re-installing*.
- Adding "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7" to "Path", without removing the above Path addition, and re-installing*.
- Adding "C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jre7" to "Path", and verified it was the proper folder, and re-installing*.
- Changing JAVA_HOME from "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0" to "C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK17~1.0", and verified it properly forwards back to the original folder in Windows, and re-installing*.
- Re-installing Java to a non-space folder, "C:\xxx\xxx\jdk1.7.0", where the x's are letters not spaces, and verified it works properly with "java -version" command line, and re-installing**.

*Downloading and installing jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jre.exe

**Downloading and installing jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jdk.exe

None of this worked. :(

I have not tried:

- Using an older JRE than 7 (1.7)

Any help would be great.

POSSIBLE (HACK) SOLUTION: What about manual installation? It's what we've opted to do at work. Is it possible to figure out what files are installed (without installing it since I cannot)?

EDIT: I have also verified that "JAI (Java Advanced Imaging) Image I/O" has the same problems on my system.

Comment: Where does the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable point?

Comment: JAVA_HOME points to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0 (not the JRE, the JDK).

Comment: Go to command prompt... type javac -version

Comment: Also what is "PATH" enviorment variable value?

Comment: Delta, I have updated what the "Path" environment variable was set to.

Comment: Delta again, I have run "javac- version" but I am in the middle of a reinstall of all my development tools, and Java has already been reinstalled (to a new location that does not contain spaces). But when I run "javac- version" now, in my NEW INSTALL I get "javac 1.7.0", and likely this is what I got before.

Comment: Just installed jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jdk.exe in jdk1.6.0_22_x32 and jdk1.6.0_22_x64 without issue. My OS is also Windows 7 x64

Comment: Thanks mgamulin, I'm not sure what I'm missing. :(

Comment: Can you please install Jdk at c:\java\jdknew location. Set JAVA_HOME=c:\java\jdknew  remove java reference from PATH and add %JAVA_HOME%\bin; at the end of path variable. If possible paste screenshot and paste output of javac -version command

Comment: Martin, when you installed JAI into JDK 1.6 64-bit, are you sure it wasn't detecting your 32-bit install? There is an answer posted below that says JAI is 32-bit and will not install into 64-bit JRE. I'm curious which of you is correct. Address it below if you would like.

Comment: Delta, not sure if this helps, but I have Java installed to "D:\xxx\xxx\jdk1.7.0" and JAVA_HOME=D:\xxx\xxx\jdk1.7.0, and Path=D:\opt\wsp\jdk1.7.0\bin, and "javac -version" returns "javac 1.7.0". 

(P.S. "xxx" are folders comprised of letters, no spaces, which I am hiding for security's sake, in case it matters.)

Comment: Install 1.6.0_24 instead of 1.7?

Answer (score 6):

JAI is only available on 32bit (x86) JRE, so you need to install the 32 bit JRE on Windows 7.

JAI uses some native implementations (dlls) in order to accelerate the processing, so only installs on a 32bit JRE.

When installing JAI, it tries to detect the installed JRE and should be a 32bit JRE. You can install 32bit JRE on a Windows 7 x64, the only "difference" is the performance and the maximum memory available to java applications.

Install JAva 7 JRE 32bit from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jre-7-download-432155.html select "Windows x86 Offline".

Another way is manual installation from JAI as zip, use jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586.jar.zip and execute from the 32bit JRE.

Comment: I am going to test my manual install of JAI (into my 64-bit install of JDK) and get back to you.

Please note the comment on the OP that says, "Just installed jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jdk.exe in jdk1.6.0_22_x32 and jdk1.6.0_22_x64 without issue. My OS is also Windows 7 x64 – Martin Gamulin Sep 6 at 19:52". This appears to contradict what you are saying that it doesn't work on 64-bit.

Comment: Maybe, at this moment I only remember JAI native acceleration (dlls) only works with 32bit JREs and no x64 version is available.

Answer (score 3):

install a JRE version 1.3 or later?  (and make sure that your PATH points to it)

[edit]
Are you sure there's a problem?  It seems that 3 files you downloaded are mutually exclusive (that's what I got from reading the installation instructions)

```
http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jdk.exe
http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jre.exe
http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586.exe
```

Installing -jre or -jdk may be redundant
I installed the jre version and it asked me for a jre directory - any of that happen to you?
[/edit]

Comment: Oops, I should have mentioned I have JRE 7 (1.7) installed at "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7", just double checked, and my path does not point to it, just doubled checked that too. I wasn't aware I needed to do this, from previous experience installing this on my Windows XP machine.

Comment: I have pointed my path to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin" and this did not help remove the error.

Comment: Did you point the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable @ c:\program files\java\jre7 ?

Comment: Yes, JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0" (without quotes).

Comment: Maybe c:\progra~1\java\jdk1.7.0 (or to use the JRE - c:\progra~1\java\jre7)?

Comment: I just tried (adding to) Path = "C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jre7" and verified it was the proper folder... didn't work. :(

Then I tried JAVA_HOME = "C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK17~1.0" and verified it was the proper folder... didn't work. :(

Comment: @KevinDTimm , i want to know what is the output of javac -version command?

Comment: Regarding your edit concerning exclusivity: I think you are right, but since I was not sure what would be using JAI here at my work, I wanted to install all three. The first installs to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Sun Microsystems\Java Advanced Imaging 1.1.3" and the other two should install under my JDK and JRE locations (and remember that JDK also has it's own JRE location within it, so who knows what it does there). I could probably just copy these files manually into their destined locations, if I knew it was the same thing.

Comment: What about manual installation? It's what we've opted to do at work. Is it possible to figure out what files are installed (without installing it since I cannot)?

Answer (score 1):

try to install (reinstall) java (jre) in folder without any spaces. For example C:\Java\jre7.

Comment: I too have found that embedded 'program files' and java installations are not great friends - YMMV

Comment: Hmmm... well I just tried changing JAVA_HOME to "C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK17~1.0" and verified it was the proper folder which properly forwards to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0" in Windows, and re-installed JAI (for JRE) and it gave the same error. Not sure if this properly tests this.

Comment: Well, not really. If you want to give it a try deinstall jre and install it in path without spaces. By the way, did you try it with older jre?

Comment: I did not try it with an older JRE, but I'm about to try the no-space location install... later today.

Comment: Given Java can easily deal with spaces in directory or file names, I fail to see how any of this is relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: I'm going to install not just Java, but everything on my workstation setup that relates to this in anyway, to a no-space location and get back to you if it works or not. There ends up being other reasons this is a good thing for me to do, outside of this problem, to better emulate the production server.

Comment: I'm back. I have tried installing Java into an C:\xxx\xxx\jdk1.7.0 and C:\xxx\xxx\jre7 folders, where the x's are letters not spaces. And it gives the same error, this time just for JDK version (jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jdk.exe), but assuming the JRE version does the same. I will edit my post to speak more about the JDK version as this is what I want and the errors are similar for both.

Comment: What about manual installation? It's what we've opted to do at work. Is it possible to figure out what files are installed (without installing it since I cannot)?

Answer (score 1):

You must install 32-bit version of jdk

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing 32-bit version of jdk.
My OS is window 8 64-bit. 
when installing jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jdk.exe and jai_imageio-1_1-lib-windows-i586-jdk.exe with double clicks, i got the same error "Severe: JRE 1.3 or higher must be installed!"
then I downloaded jdk-7u21-windows-i586.exe and installed it in "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java".
and then it's OK.